# How can I fix the Chromium browser's "Aw, Snap!" bug without losing all of my user profile info?

Tags: chromium, ubuntu-11.10

I'm getting the "Aw, Snap!" bug quite often these days when trying to watch videos with the Chromium browser on Ubuntu 11.10.

The help page says that my user profile is broken, and while creating a new one does solve the problem, I hate losing all that information every month when the bug re-occurs. Does anyone know which part of the user profile is corrupted when this happens? I'm just looking for a way to fix this problem without having to lose all my user profile information.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answers to this question [Backing up Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/13929/backing-up-google-chrome). The accepted answer gives the location of your user profile in Windows and detailed instructions for what to back up. According to another answer (haven't checked, don't use chromium) you will want to look in ~/.cache/google-chrome/Cache and ~/.cache/google-chrome/Media\ Cache.