# Extension to Google Chrome browser that restarts Google Chrome

Tags: browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions

I'm looking for an extension to Google Chrome that performs the same task as an extension I use all the time in Mozilla Firefox.

[The extension in Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/sotarok/?src=api) stops the Firefox *browser* and starts it again, allowing for the default "crash recovery" behavior to take place of remembering the tabs and restoring them. It does this with the click of a button:

[image]

Does any such thing exist in Chrome? While I prefer a button, I can live with a keyboard shortcut, or even a right click.

Comment: You can set Chrome to reopen your previous session when it is started. Then just exit Chrome from the browser menu and start it again. That's what I do anyway :P

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Type this into the omnibox (address bar):

`chrome://restart`

Comment: Apparently [people prefer](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/eL_kaH10SNA) a button to typing things in. Besides, the question isn’t really about restarting, it’s about session-management.

Comment: Brilliant! This is exactly what I was looking for! This can be bookmarked or macroed to a key command with with Alt-D before it. I had given up on finding something so simple and elegant and you came to the rescue!

Comment: @Keyslinger, you should still use a proper session-management extension instead of relying on Chrome’s crash-recovery.

Comment: You can turn this into a button easily, by making it a bookmark. You can even put it inside a folder, to make it take two clicks. I put it at the bottom of my "Other Bookmarks" folder.

Answer (score 5):

If you [search the webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/restart), you’ll find at least [one extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/restart-your-browser/cpfmhdgpigoebiiccopgpbjacndhldoo) that can do it (at least according to the one person who reviewed it).

If you only want it in order to save your session, then you are asking the wrong question. It is not advisable to depend on Chrome’s crash-recovery to save your session because it is not always reliable. <sup>[[1]](https://superuser.com/questions/635436/can-i-restore-closed-tabs-after-quitting-chrome) [[2]](https://superuser.com/questions/244325/how-to-restore-the-window-of-tabs-crashed-1-day-ago-in-google-chrome)</sup>

You should use a proper session-management extension instead. A good one is [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko) which is very powerful, yet easy to use.

Comment: Session Buddy looks awesome. Great functionality compared to Chrome's built-in "Continue where I left off" function. +1

Comment: `Chrome's built-in "Continue where I left off" function` …or more accurately, Chrome’s *continue where I left off sometimes and other times, just pretend the crash never happened and hope the user doesn’t notice and forgets about the tabs they were using* function.

Comment: No need for an extension, plug-in, or add-on. The feature is baked right into Chrome itself: `chrome://restart`.